# can't install ros-electric-ros-full

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-natty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having an issue where I upgraded something, which caused ros-electric-geometry to get removed. I went to reinstall it with apt-get, and it wouldn't install (said it depended on something that wasn't going to be installed), so I removed ALL of my ROS stuff (purge, autoremove, update). Now when I try to install ros-full, I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-ros-full : Depends: ros-electric-rx (= 1.6.1-s1323597255~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: ros-electric-ros-comm (= 1.6.6-s1323590699~natty) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: ros-electric-documentation (= 1.4.3-s1323617999~natty) but it is not going to be installed
```

If I follow the chain of unmet dependences through, I eventually get here:

```
$ sudo apt-get install krb5-multidev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 krb5-multidev : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libk5crypto3 (= 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2 (= 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2) but 1.8.3+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
```

I've seen problems like this before, but haven't had luck with any of the solutions out there. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12693/can%27t-install-ros-electric-ros-full/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to resolve this by using aptitude instead of apt-get, and cycling through its solutions until I found one that actually installed the packages I wanted.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Possible duplicates:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/3408/ros-electric-installation-problem
- http://answers.ros.org/question/3237/unmet-dependencies-when-install-ros-electric

Essentially the answer boils down to:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And if that didn't work

```
sudo apt-get clean all
```

And then try your install command again.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-01-19**:
Didn't work. None of the suggestions in the linked posts helps either, unfortunately.